# Gradle Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.4/ very slow and failed

Tags: maven, android-studio, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I'm in China and use proxy.
My config:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

[image: config]

when Gradle sync,it always shows

[image: problem]

I also search the jar in my computer and i find i have this jar.
i also can enter the:  `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.4/`

why? what can i do?
Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the Network.
so if it's not very urgent.
How about stop download it and choose a nice time to continue download it.

Answer (score 0):

download the gradle.zip to your local folder and change the distribution url in gradlebuilder file.

Comment: what means?D:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-2.14.1,it's ok.

Comment: gradle-wrapper.properties:distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip what should i do?

Comment: yes, But you should specify the path in your gradle builder.

Comment: download the gradle and copy to D:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/

set 
     distributionUrl = 'D:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-2.14.1.zip';

Comment: distributionUrl='D:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-2.14.1.zip’ or distributionUrl=D:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-2.14.1.zip or distributionUrl=D\:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-2.14.1.zip,but it still download.

Comment: D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.14.1\lib have groovy-all-2.4.4.jar.

Comment: may be gradle-2.14.1-all.zip and gradle-2.14.1.zip is different. i also use distributionUrl=C\:/Users/car/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip but failed.

Comment: distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=C\:/Users/car/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip the path will have some influence?

Comment: i'd  the same issue while building apk using cordova platform. changing the distribution url gradle builde helped me.

Comment: Thanks a lot.i meet the issue when i sync Gradle.